# iPhone 6+ state restoration with tab bar in master split view

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, iphone-6-plus, state-restoration

I have a problem with supporting state restoration in iPhone 6+.

Here's my hierarchy:
[image]

Problem is when state restoration happens in Portrait orientation and then, at later point, state decoding attempt is made while in Landscape orientation.

Explanation:
In portrait mode, there is only TabBar as master view (in fact, detail view doesn't exist) so it is pushed into TabBar navigation's controller.

Then, at later point, when app tries to perform state restoration for landscape, my details view is pushed onto master navigation controller (when it should be in details).

Due to custom hierarchy I have implemented UISplitViewControllerDelegate methods accordingly, and they work fine.
UISplitViewControllerDelegate methods also make sure that state restoration works in following cases:

```
Landscape -> Landscape
Landscape -> Portrait
 Portrait -> Portrait
```

what's not working is: Portrait -> Landscape because, as I said, delegate method don't get called when in not-collapsed state so view hierarchy doesn't know how to split details from master view and embed that into detail navigation controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UISplitViewController state restoration in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850786/uisplitviewcontroller-state-restoration-in-ios-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I have solved it like this: in viewWillAppear all detail controllers are cut from tab bar's navigation controllers.
When storing state, device orientation is saved and SplitViewController.viewControllers (for me it won't store them automatically as it does on iOS7).

```
- (void) encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
{
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
    [coder encodeObject:self.viewControllers forKey:@"viewControllers"];
    [coder encodeInteger:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation forKey:@"orientation"];
}

- (void) decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
{
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
    NSArray* viewControllers = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"viewControllers"];
    if (viewControllers.count > 0)
    {
        self.viewControllers = viewControllers;
    }
    restoredOrientation = (UIInterfaceOrientation) [coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

And here is viewWillAppear implementation:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // iPhone6+: if state restoration happened while in portrait orientation and app is launched while in landscape,
    // then all detail views should be cut from master view and split details view is set appropriately
    if (firstLoad &&
            [UIScreen mainScreen].scale > 2.9 && // assure it's iPhone 6+
            UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(restoredOrientation) &&
            UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarOrientation))
    {
        UITabBarController* tbc = self.viewControllers[0];
        NSArray* detachedControllers = [tbc cutControllersFrom:DocumentViewController.class];
        if (detachedControllers.count > 0)
        {
            UINavigationController* documentNavigation = [self.storyboard
                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationController"];
            documentNavigation.viewControllers = detachedControllers;
            self.viewControllers = @[ self.viewControllers[0], documentNavigation ];
        }
        else // place some default no-selection controller in detail
        {
            UINavigationController* noSelectionNavigation = [self.storyboard
                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NoSelectionSID"];
            self.viewControllers = @[ self.viewControllers.firstObject, noSelectionNavigation ];
        }
    }
    firstLoad = NO;
}
```

where cutControllersFrom method is a category on UITabBarController:

```
- (NSArray*) cutControllersFrom:(Class)controllerClass
{
    NSArray* ret;
    for (UIViewController* vc in self.viewControllers)
    {
        if (![vc isKindOfClass:UINavigationController.class])
        {
            continue;
        }

        UINavigationController* nc = (UINavigationController*) vc;
        NSArray* removed = [nc cutFrom:controllerClass];
        if (vc == self.selectedViewController)
        {
            ret = removed;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

which calls cutFrom: method which is a category on UINavigationController:

```
- (NSArray*) cutFrom:(Class)controllerClass
{
    NSMutableArray* toRemove = [NSMutableArray array];
    BOOL startRemoving = NO;
    UIViewController* endingViewController;

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.viewControllers.count; i++)
    {
        UIViewController* vc = self.viewControllers[i];
        if ([vc isKindOfClass:controllerClass])
        {
            startRemoving = YES;
            endingViewController = self.viewControllers[i - 1];
        }

        if (startRemoving)
        {
            [toRemove addObject:vc];
        }
    }
    if (endingViewController)
    {
        [self popToViewController:endingViewController animated:NO];
    }

    return toRemove;
}
```

Comment: Seems you have little choice and well done on figuring all this out. If you were up for an approach change, one option would be to not use tab bars and move to a side bar. I do this in my current app where a side menu lets me switch between multiple split view controllers. Good thing is each split view is separate and has navigation controllers for master and detail, so simpler. So your tab bar could become the side bar menu which would let you switch between 4 split view controllers: one for each ControllerX. Just a thought.

Comment: Ah yes, side menu is a neet idea. For now, I have to stick with TabBar, but for future reference, it would be very good to keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your problem as going from Portrait to Landscape on iPhone 6+ should go from a collapsed state to a split state so should call this delegate:

`- (UIViewController *)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController
separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController`

However you seem to imply this is not called and in Portrait it is in a non collapsed state?

On the split view controllers I use I have found it best to let the controller sort things out for itself. If you use showDetail segues for the detail view it should handle the split for you. Are you making sure to use showDetail segues to push the DetailController from your Controller1->4 rather than show segues?

Hence assuming you are using the correct segues to the detail, just return nil in the delegates to let the split view controller sort itself out?

Comment: SplitViewController can sort things out if master is UINavigationController, but in my case it is UITabBarController which has it's own UINavigationControllers, and that's something UISplitViewController doesn't know how to sort out, so I had to do it manually by implementing UISplitViewControllerDelegate methods.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps you need to implement `- splitViewController:showDetailViewController:sender:` in your split view controller to let you put the detail in the correct place?

Comment: I am already implementing that method, but that one is not called upon state restoration.

Answer (score 0):

When state is preserved in portrait, the restoration identifier paths will be different from the expected landscape which is the default initial state when using the split view controller. i.e. the detail is in the primary instead of in the secondary. So when the app is relaunched it won't be able to re-create the previous hierarchy and will resort to recreating those controllers in their separated configuration (Step 4 in [About the UI Restoration Process](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/preserving_your_app_s_ui_across_launches/about_the_ui_restoration_process?language=objc)) which means `separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController` will not be called because the controls are already separated. You might notice when on start up two detail controllers are created the first one that likely has default properties set on it being thrown away, or you might even see two detail controllers pushed on the nav stack. I'm not sure why you managed to get Portrait->Portrait working as it should suffer the same issues.

To solve these problems you could implement `application:viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:coder` which (in the Portrait->Landscape scenario) will be called with the portrait hierarchy and you could return the existing view controllers by searching for them in the hierarchy that was loaded from the storyboard. After it has restored the view controllers it will detect that there has been an orientation change from the preserved portrait to the current landscape and `separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController` will get called. However, I'm not yet certain that this is the right approach given that there is some state in the split controller that is not saved, like `_preservedDetailController` for example (which is how the split view controller can automatically separate the controllers after a previous collapse) so there is a chance that we are supposed to just throw state away if there is a relaunch after orientation change I'm not 100% sure yet.

Here is an example from my test app:

```
- (UIViewController *)application:(UIApplication *)application viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:(NSArray *)identifierComponents coder:(NSCoder *)coder{
    if([identifierComponents.lastObject isEqualToString:@"DetailViewController"]){
        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UINavigationController *secondaryNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers.lastObject;;
        DetailViewController *detail = (DetailViewController *)secondaryNavigationController.viewControllers.firstObject;
        NSURL *objectURI = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"object"];
        if(objectURI){
            NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.persistentContainer.viewContext;
            NSManagedObjectID *objectID = [moc.persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:objectURI];
            NSManagedObject *object = [moc objectWithID:objectID];
            detail.object = object;
        }
        // attempt to workaround a bug for _preservedDetailController not being restored.
        [splitViewController _willShowCollapsedDetailViewController:secondaryNavigationController inTargetController:nil];
        return detail;
    }
    else if([identifierComponents.lastObject isEqualToString:@"DetailNavigationController"]){
        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UINavigationController *secondaryNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers.lastObject;
        return secondaryNavigationController;
    }
    return nil;
}
```